# Couple of questions on Hurwitz theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

**Hurwitz theorem** as stated in [Hahn and Epstein's Classical Complex Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/086720494X) is as follows:

[image]

Comment: By "real functions" I assume you mean real-valued functions that are not necessarily analytic; otherwise there would be no example that fails.

Answer (score 2):

For (2), assuming you mean real-analytic $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$: take $f_n(x)=x^2+\frac1n$, which has no real roots, converging to $f(x)=x^2$ which has a (double) root $x=0$.

For (1), yes.  Let $f_n(z)=f(z)+a_n$, $a_n\to 0$ and Rouché's theorem to get a root of $f_n$ sufficient close $z_0$.

Comment: Ah, very nice.  The complex roots of  $f_n(x) = x^2+\frac1n$ you give do have $0$ as an accumulation point, but by restricting to real roots, you wipe out that accumulation point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related question.

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic functions on a domain $D$
> converging uniformly on every compact subset of $D$ to a function $f$.
> Suppose that $f$ has a simple zero $z_0 \in D$. Show that there is a
> neighborhood of $z_0$, say $N(z_0) \subset D$ and an integer $n_0>0$
> such that for each $n > n_0$, $f_n$ has a simple zero in $N(z_0)$.